# eventos play() y pause() Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

viendo tutoriales para practicar realice xilófono (instrumento musical) y cree un par de botones que reproducen un ritmo con determinadas de notas.

Mi problema es que si doy click a uno de los btn para reproducir un ritmo e inmediatamente le doy a otro btn los dos ritmos se solapan... Como haría para hacer de se detuviera el primer ritmo si le doy click a otro?

Dejo el código a continuación:

```
// do 0
// re 1
// mi 2
// fa 3
// sol 4
// la 5
// si 6
// do+ 7

var notes = $('.sound');

var note1 = [0,0,0,3,5,  0,0,0,3,5,  3,3,2,2,1,1,0,  0,0,0,2,4,  0,0,0,2,4,  7,7,6,5,4,3,1,0];
var tempo1 = [1,1,1,2,3,  1,1,1,2,3,  1,1,1,1,1,1,3,  1,1,1,2,3,  1,1,1,2,3,  2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];

var note2 = [2,2,2,  2,2,2,  2,4,0,1,2,  3,3,3,  3,2,2,  2,1,1,2,1,4,  2,2,2,  2,2,2,  2,4,0,1,2,  3,3,3,  3,2,2,  4,4,3,1,0];
var tempo2 = [1,1,2,  1,1,2,  1,1,1,1,4,  1,1,2,  1,1,2,  1,1,1,1,2,2,  1,1,2,  1,1,2,  1,1,1,1,4,  1,1,2,  1,1,2,  1,1,1,1,4];

var note3 = [0,0,1,0,3,2,  0,0,1,0,4,3,  0,0,7,5,3,3,2,1,  6,6,5,3,4,3];
var tempo3 = [2,1,2,2,2,3,  2,1,2,2,2,3,  2,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,  2,1,2,2,2,3];

var note4 = [0,0,4,4,5,5,4,5,5,2,2,1,1,0,  4,4,3,3,2,2,1,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,  0,0,4,4,5,5,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,0];
var tempo4 = [2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,  2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,  2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,3];

var note5 = [7,7,5,6,4,7,7,5,6,4,7,7,6,5,4,3,1,  6,6,5,4,3,1,1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1,0];
var tempo5 =[1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,  1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2];

$('.note').click(function() {
  var num = parseInt(this.id);
  play(num);
});

$('#btn1').click(function() {
  var count = 0;
  for(var i= 0; i < note1.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(sound) {
      play(note1[sound]);
    }, rhythm1(i) * 350, i);
  }
});

$('#btn2').click(function() {
  var count = 0;
  for(var i= 0; i < note2.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(sound) {
      play(note2[sound]);
    }, rhythm2(i) * 350, i);
  }
});

$('#btn3').click(function() {
  var count = 0;
  for(var i= 0; i < note3.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(sound) {
      play(note3[sound]);
    }, rhythm3(i) * 350, i);
  }
});

$('#btn4').click(function() {
  var count = 0;
  for(var i= 0; i < note4.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(sound) {
      play(note4[sound]);
    }, rhythm4(i) * 350, i);
  }
});

$('#btn5').click(function() {
  var count = 0;
  for(var i= 0; i < note5.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(sound) {
      play(note5[sound]);
    }, rhythm5(i) * 350, i);
  }
});

function play(num) {
  notes[num].pause();
  notes[num].currentTime = 0;
  notes[num].play();
  $("#" + num).css({
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "color": "#FCFBE3"
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#" + num).css({
      "font-weight": "normal",
      "color": "#3a2f21"
    });
  }, 300);
}

function rhythm1(num) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < num ; i++) {
    count = count + tempo1[i];
  }
  return count;
}

function rhythm2(num) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < num ; i++) {
    count = count + tempo2[i];
  }
  return count;
}

function rhythm3(num) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < num ; i++) {
    count = count + tempo3[i];
  }
  return count;
}

function rhythm4(num) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < num ; i++) {
    count = count + tempo4[i];
  }
  return count;
}

function rhythm5(num) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < num ; i++) {
    count = count + tempo5[i];
  }
  return count;
}
```

Si le doy click al boton#btn1 y luego hago click en el boton#btn2 como podría hacer para detener con el evento pause() el ritmo del boton#btn1?

un estoy aprendiendo y pues lo que hice fue replicar el mismo método del boton#bn1 para los otros botones. No se si esta bien tener una function para cada botón o es mejor detectarlos todos por medio de una clase y dependiendo luego de ID de cada botón ejecutar la función o guardar los botones en un array...

Espero me haya explicado bien, igual dejo el link donde esta funcionando, saludos. http://codepen.io/cartalan/pen/NjPJjj

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías Matar los Timeouts con la Funcion clearTimeout

```
clearTimeout(timer1)
```

Deberías asignar los timeouts a una Variable (timer1) para poder matarlos de ésta manera.

Comment: Oye gracias lo tendre en cuenta!